# Which are the differences between the verbs "to say" and "to tell"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verbs, spoken-english, writing

i don't know in which contexts I have to use One of these two verbs? 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have specific examples that you are unclear about? Please [edit] these into the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[say](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/say)** (v): Utter words so as to convey information, an opinion, a feeling or intention, or an instruction.
>
> **[tell](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tell)** (v): Communicate information **to someone** in spoken or written words.

At a basic level, "say" is to utter information out loud.  "Tell" is to the same thing, *to other people*.  This is why "say" has only a direct object,

> I have **something** I want to say.

while "tell" normally has both a direct and an indirect object.

> I have **something** I want to tell **you**.

[Not quite a duplicate question, but more information](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34115/say-something-vs-tell-something-to-somebody)

Keep in mind that both "say" and "tell" are fundamental verbs with *many* definitions, all of which you should learn by hearing native speakers use them in context.  For example:

> A: It's so hot!  What does the thermometer **say**?
>   B: I can't **tell**.  The humidity has fogged up the glass.